# How to change port in mysql in cnf file

Tags: mysql

I keep trying to change the port number in mysql with a current db that I am using. FOr some reason each time I use this port my spring application throws an error saying the port is already in use even though I use the `kill -9 PID` command to kill whatever processes is listening on that port. Anyways I used the `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and created a variable port=3307 like I was told online when searching for a solution. I then restarted mysql using `sudo service mysql restart` but whenever I enter mysql and enter  `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';` it keeps showing up as 3306. The following is my cnf file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
port=3307
```

Please help I have been stuck on this for hours and can't seem to solve it. Also if there is anyway that I could just use port 3306 without having to kill it each time I start up that would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: [tag:spring-boot] doesn't have anything to do with MySQL configuration files. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

port needs to be under a `[mysqld]` or equivalent section.

Don't `kill -9` on databases. They will terminate eventually. Use service controls like systemctl/service.

Comment: My cnf file looks like this now ```
....
[mysqld]
port=3307
```but when I check the port in mysql on my terminal it still comes up as 3306

Comment: Oh it worked I had to reset mysql services for it to take effect. Thanks!